# In BigQuery SQL: To check and update table column value on satisfying the date constraints

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery, left-join

Have got a bigquery table structured as below:

```
Store       Product     Weekbegindate   Weekenddate     Datevalidfrom   Datevalidto     IP      Unit
11          AA          2021-02-24      2021-03-02      null            null            null    7.7
11          BB          2021-02-10      2021-02-16      2021-04-17      2021-12-01      44      59.9
11          CC          2021-06-09      2021-06-15      2021-06-03      2021-06-24      03      6.5
```

I need to update '`Unit`' column on satisfing two conditions,
1. Check if '`IP`' IS NOT NULL and also validate dates starting from '`Weekbegindate`' ending with '`Weekenddate`' - lies between the date range '`Datevalidfrom`' and '`Datevalidto`'
2. If 'yes' then update '`Unit`' column to value '`0`' else retain the same value.

**Expected Output:**

```
Store       Product     Weekbegindate   Weekenddate     Datevalidfrom   Datevalidto     IP      Unit
11          AA          2021-02-24      2021-03-02      null            null            null    7.7
11          BB          2021-02-10      2021-02-16      2021-04-17      2021-12-01      44      59.9
11          CC          2021-06-09      2021-06-15      2021-06-03      2021-06-24      03      0
```

**Tried Query:**

```
SELECT t1.*,
      CASE WHEN (tt1.Store AND tt1.Product AND tt1.Weekbegindate AND tt1.Weekenddate) IS NOT NULL
      THEN 0 ELSE t1.Unit END as ip_Unit
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM table1 
      where IP is not null 
        and Datevalidfrom between Weekbegindate and Weekenddate
        or Datevalidto between Weekbegindate and Weekenddate
        or Weekbegindate between Datevalidfrom and Datevalidto
        or Weekenddate between Datevalidfrom and Datevalidto) tt1 
ON t1.Store = tt1.Store AND t1.Product = tt1.Product AND t1.Weekbegindate = tt1.Weekbegindate AND t1.Weekenddate = tt1.Weekenddate
```

But this doesn't workout.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `case` expression:

```
select t1.* (except unit),
       (case when ip is not null and
                  Weekbegindate >= Datevalidfrom and
                  Weekenddate <= Datevalidto
             then 0 else unit
        end) as unit
from t1;
```

This logic can also be incorporated into an `update`.